# What kind of attorney do I need to do the city for violating my 4th amendment?

Tags: united-states, property, fourth-amendment

Can the city have my truck towed out of my driveway? The tags are up today and I'm working on it with no warning.

Comment: Has the city given you a reason for the tow?   And is "your drive way" on "your property"?

Comment: We rent the property and it was broke down in the front yd about 3 months ago and they tagged it End gave us 10 calendar days to move ithen I fixed it and it was in my driveway and it broke down again Me andand my daughter was replacing a coil and they came in towed it said it was a Junk vehicle but it's tag Registered And up-to-date Is there anything I can do

Comment: Driveways may not be your property in every sense. City ordinances may explicitly forbid you from repairing a vehicle in your driveway.

Comment: Before engaging a lawyer, consider checking if the city has an appeals process.

Comment: How would I go about finding that out

Comment: How can I check if the city has an appeal on it is kind of free will cost me money

Comment: Lots of cities have ordinances against non-functioning cars in your own driveway. Being registered doesn't help.

Comment: What state?  What city?

Comment: Generally speaking, in the USA both sides pay their own legal costs, win or lose. But it's worth talking to a lawyer: they will do a free initial consultation in which they explain the law and give you an idea of the likely costs of proceeding.

Comment: To find out about the law, google for the local ordinances in your city. Also find the city hall web site and see if you can locate the relevant information there. With luck there will be an on-line payment facility which will tell you which rule you are alleged to have broken and point you at the appeals process. Do some research, then check back here if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need a lawyer who handles civil-rights law. Fourth Amendment search-and-seizure law is the heart of most police-misconduct claims, so you should look for a lawyer who handles that type of work: false arrest, malicious prosecution, excessive force, etc.